# Adding focus to a parent element on focus child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to highlight a parent `<ul>` when focus is on `<li>` child element. I am using jQuery to achieve this, but the focus will not transfer.

HTML:

```
 ul class="nav @if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice){@Html.Raw("nav-pills")}else{@Html.Raw("nav-pills")}">
            <li class="dropdown" style="cursor:pointer" id="accessFunction">
   <a style="color: lightgray; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #111; webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #111;font-size:18px;background-color:transparent;padding-right:5px" class="dropdown-toggle subTabAction" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropAccess" >
```

jQuery:

```
$('#dropAccess').focus()
$(this).find('#accessFunction').focus();
```

This is being done to accommodate keyboard only users that need visual ques to find the accessible dropdown menu that is triggered by the `<li>` tag.

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/progSrCa/d3au7k9c/

Update:

I realized that the issue is with the 'ul' and 'li' relationship, and I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this, please? BTW your code is not so clear.

Comment: If looking at accessibility also look at [aria-posinset](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-posinset) and [aria-setsize](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-setsize)

Comment: @kodecount I have added the code, but it is being generated from an asp.net partial, and I have limited access to full functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger focus either from the focus of another input, or on clicking on a given div. This is the required jQuery code. Se fiddle for full example.

```
$( "#otherInput" ).focus(function() {
  $( "#target" ).focus();
});

$( "#plainDiv" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).focus();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q0m4hff9/

Comment: @Kristfral Thank you very much, this cleared up my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to focus an list element (li). I believe you can focus HTML Select, textarea, input, button, and a tags. you can try force the focus by adding tabindex attribute to your element to add. You can still do some tricks with jquery by triggering the focus handler but not event.

```
$('#accessFunction').triggerHandler( "focus" );
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3au7k9c/2/)

Comment: to clarify, what I was attempting to do was add focus to a parent element, when the interior child is targeted. I can target the tab focused element "subTabAction" and gain focus, I was looking to add a visual indicator to that element when focused.